How to solve transient error when migrating database using PowerShell/EF6 commands?
I am trying to create an Azure DevOps pipeline to migrate database using PowerShell and EF6. Here is my code:
 steps:
- powershell: |
    $binPath = {some-path}
    $ef6Exe = $binPath + "\ef6.exe"
    $assemblyPath = $binPath + "\application.Data.dll"
    $projectDir = $binPath
    
    & $ef6Exe migrations enable --assembly $assemblyPath --project-dir $projectDir --force
    & $ef6Exe migrations add 2024_MyMigration --assembly $assemblyPath --project-dir $projectDir --force --connection-string "$(ConnectionString)" --connection-provider System.Data.SqlClient
    & $ef6Exe database update --assembly $assemblyPath --project-dir $projectDir --connection-string "$(ConnectionString)" --connection-provider System.Data.SqlClient
  displayName: 'Migrate DB'

However, I got an error saying:
System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure. If you are connecting to a SQL Azure database consider using SqlAzureExecutionStrategy. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process.
It looks like the line causing the error is below, where I am trying to connect to the database when making an update/migration.
& $ef6Exe database update --assembly $assemblyPath --project-dir $projectDir --connection-string "$(ConnectionString)" --connection-provider System.Data.SqlClient

I looked this up and according to this documentation, I need to implement a retry logic.
steps:
- powershell: |
    $binPath = {some-path}
    ef6Exe = $binPath + "\ef6.exe"
    $assemblyPath = $binPath + "\application.Data.dll"
    $projectDir = $binPath

    $maxRetries = 5
    $retryIntervals = @(5, 10, 20, 40, 60)
    $attempt = 0
    $success = $false

    & $ef6Exe migrations enable --assembly $assemblyPath --project-dir $projectDir --force
    & $ef6Exe migrations add 2024_MyMigration --assembly $assemblyPath --project-dir $projectDir --force --connection-string "$(ConnectionString)" --connection-provider System.Data.SqlClient

    while (-not $success -and $attempt -lt $maxRetries) {
        try {
            Write-Output 'Attempting task...'
            
            & $ef6Exe database update --assembly $assemblyPath --project-dir $projectDir --connection-string "$(ConnectionString)" --connection-provider System.Data.SqlClient
            if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0) { throw "Command failed with exit code $LASTEXITCODE" }
            
            $success = $true
        } catch {
            Write-Output "Attempt $($attempt + 1) failed. Retrying in $($retryIntervals[$attempt]) seconds..."
            Start-Sleep -Seconds $retryIntervals[$attempt]
            $attempt++
        }
    }

    if (-not $success) {
        throw "Task failed after $maxRetries attempts."
    }
  displayName: 'Migrate DB'

Even with the retry logic, I still can't get it to work. It just re-executes the failed line of code over and over until it fails again. Anyone encountered this issue before? I would like to get some guidance.
